# (ValueError: Couldn't parse date string) When trying to import sqlite table to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I am having trouble importing DATE and TIMESTAMP values from sqlite into pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlaclchemy

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///database.db')
df = pd.read_sql_table('ephemeris', engine)
print(df)



ValueError: Couldn't parse date string: '1943 1 1'
```

When I run another table which starts with a DATE value I get the following

```
ValueError:Couldn't parse datetime string: '00:00:00'
```

I'm having trouble finding information on this. I could convert the columns from DATE and TIMESTAMP to TEXT and I think it would solve the problem. But I Was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: You could try using parse_dates parameter `df = pd.read_sql('ephemeris', engine, parse_dates = {'column_name':'%Y %m %d'})` [read more](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was not sure how to use parse_dates, however it still did not fix the problem. I wonder if DATE and TIMESTAMP are not proper ways to import data into sqlite?

Comment: I went ahead and changed DATE to TEXT and it worked perfectly. I used parse_dates to format it correctly and index_col to set it as the index.

Comment: @muraaby : please post your answer so people can follow later. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I changed DATE and TIMESTAMP to TEXT. This corrected the problem, I was a little suspicious when reading up on the sqlite datatypes, I stumbled upon a few sources that stated DATE and TIMESTAMP were unofficially supported. However this is my mistake and I will be sticking to the official data types.

TEXT
NUMERIC
INTEGER
REAL
BLOB

Here is the official documentation on handling dates in sqlite
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html